# why "that" isn't used here instead of "if"?

Tags: whether-if

Considering following sentences.

- Not sure if I look so retarded or people don't understand me.
- Not sure if I walk so fast or others walk too slow.
- Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or you are trying to fool me.

Questions:
Is it formal? if no how does formal one look like?
Is it possible to use "that" instead of "if"? the difference?
When should I use this form? and is there any other way to say it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Is it formal?**

It doesn't sound especially formal to me.

**2. if no how does formal one look like?**

I would use `whether` to make it sound formal:

- Not sure **whether** I look so retarded or people don't understand me.
- Not sure **whether** I walk so fast or others walk too slow.
- Not sure **whether** I'm doing something wrong or you are trying to fool me.

**3. Is it possible to use "that" instead of "if"?**

As StoneyB points out `that` doesn't work because of `or`.

**4. the difference? When should I use this form? and is there any other way to say it?**

Use `if` or `whether` if you want to present a list of possibilities:

- I'm not sure if/whether A, B or C

Use `that` if you want to present only one possibility:

- Not sure **that** I look so retarded.
- Not sure **that** I walk so fast.
- Not sure **that** I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'that' probably does not suit there. What about thinking of some better option, the word *whether*? The reason is, when we have two alternatives, a sentence is better described with *whether*.

In your examples, neither of those two parts is conditional. For instance, your *fast walking* does not depend on the other clause and vice versa.

We use *if* if the sentence is conditional.

More information [here](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/if_and_whether.htm).

Broadly, *that* describes, *if* puts a condition, and *whether* gives options.

Comment: In this case, both *if* and *whether* can be used with the same meaning.  *Whether* isn't any better, only slightly more formal.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no a ‘conditional if’ (it does not introduce a subordinate conditional clause) in your examples, so you may replace it with ‘that’ or ‘whether’.
Vice versa is not possible, you cannot use ‘whether’ when there is a conditional clause.

Comment: *That* does not work here, with *or*.

Comment: You are right,thank you, that can introduce a condition: 'Now that I know I can do it'.